# Pycharm debugging with extra terminal script and parameters

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

How to debug the file `train.py` that need to run with following terminal script using Pycharm, e.g.

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=2 train.py --param1 --param2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closest thing in pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html, but it’s not that useful.

Consider using pytorch hooks. For example, see here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.paperspace.com/pytorch-hooks-gradient-clipping-debugging/amp/